# Is many to many equivalent to double one to many relation? SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I was wondering what is the difference between two database structures in this scenario:
*Admin can edit, delete, add `Manufacturers`. User(`Company`) can select those `Manufacturers`, so that they are listed under their `company` account.*

What would be the differences between A relationships(twice one to many) and B relationships (many to many) when using SQLAlchemy:

[image]

In B scenario Many to Many is added like this:

```
CompMan = db.Table('CompMan',
    db.Column('companyid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('manufacturerid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('manufacturer.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

So intermediate table appears automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage to creating your own link table (version A), as opposed to SQLAlchemy's Association table (version B), is that with the former, you're able to add additional columns to your link table that have to do with the link itself. With the association table, there's only the relation between the two and nothing else. You wouldn't be able to get that link ID with the association table.

Comment: I think in scenario B you can still get ID of the link from the intermediate table, just you cannot add more columns?

Comment: I don't recall; I've always used scenario A when setting up my relationships. Of course, I've always needed the additional columns, as I will do create/mod columns to track what user is changing stuff for audit purposes.

Comment: But in scenario A you used one to many twice? Instead of many to many right?

Comment: That is the definition of a many-to-many relationship. One company can have many manufacturers, and one manufacturer can have many companies. It's the only way to programmatically implement it, and is actually what is done in the background in Scenario B. B just has some pass-through functionality so, from each table's vantage point, it seems like a one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

For constructing a many-to-many relationship you MUST have an intermediate relation such as CompMan.

At your example B you don't implement a many to many relationship since there is no table that stores the relation between Company and Manufacturer.

For clarification ask yourself: Assuming you hold id of any Company, how do find related manufacturers, and vice verse.

Comment: When adding many to many SQLAlchemy relationship, it creates intermediate table automatically between the two in scenario B.